# Using typed data templates for a single control

Tags: c#, wpf

Is there a way to assign some property of, say, a Border, to a ViewModel and have the Border's content then match whatever typed data template corresponds to that VieWModel?

This is a very contrived example, but let's say I have a usercontrol of:

```xml
<Grid>
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBox Height="30" Width="300" Margin="10" Text="{Binding IntProperty}"></TextBox>
        <TextBox Height="30" Width="300" Margin="10"></TextBox>
        <Border x:Name="SingleElement" Height="100" Width="350" BorderBrush="Red" />
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

And I have this typed data template:

```xml
<DataTemplate DataType="local:SingleItemViewModel1">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Margin="10" Text="{Binding A}"></TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Margin="10" Text="{Binding B}"></TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

In the code-behind of my user control (again, contrived) is there a property of `SingleElement` that I can assign to a new instance of `SingleItemViewModel1` such that the above DataTemplate will display inside of it?

Answer (score 0):

Assume you're bound to a view model which exposes a property called "Item" of type `SingleItem`:

After defining your data template, this should work:

```xml
<Grid>
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBox Height="30" Width="300" Margin="10" Text="{Binding IntProperty}"></TextBox>
        <TextBox Height="30" Width="300" Margin="10"></TextBox>
        <Border x:Name="SingleElement" Height="100" Width="350" BorderBrush="Red">
            <ContentControl Content="{Binding Item}"/>
        </Border>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Note that the Border is a descendent of FrameworkElement and Decorator - it has no "content" of its own, just a single visual child. Hence the ContentControl declared as its child.

Comment: I tried that, but that causes the border to just display the name of the class—Wpf_Sandbox.SingleItemViewModel1; it's not resolving the typed data template.  Is there some way to coax it to do so?

Comment: @AdamRackis The answer is found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17514824/how-to-get-contentcontrol-to-resolve-datatemplate . Basically, use {x:Type} when defining the data template instead of just the type name