# How to get ContentControl to resolve DataTemplate

Tags: wpf, datatemplate, contentcontrol

Why does this not resolve the datatemplate?

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="system:DateTime" >
        <Grid Background="Aqua">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Day}"></TextBlock>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <ContentControl Content="{x:Static system:DateTime.Now}"/>
</Grid>
```

Writing a TemplateSelector feels like an overkill.

Comment: Try use: `<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type system:DateTime}">`. Maybe help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DataType` design suggests the presence of a directive `x:Type` like that:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type system:DateTime}">
    <Grid Background="Aqua">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Day}" Height="30" Width="100" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

See the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.datatemplate.datatype.aspx) for more information.